# function expect_that from testthat runs into error

Tags: r, testthat

Can anybody help me and explain why    `expect_that`    doesn't work if `[]` is added to the stop message, i.e. `f1` works but `f2` doesn't.

```
library(testthat)
f1 <- function(x){
  if(  x >= 1 ){
    stop("error 1")
  }
}
expect_that(f1(x=1.4), throws_error("error 1"))
f2 <- function(x){
  if(  x >= 1 ){
    stop("error [1]")
  }
}
expect_that(f2(x=1.4), throws_error("error [1]"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`expect_that` is looking for a *regular expression* to match the error, so you need to escape the square-brackets so that they are interpreted literally rather than as a pattern definition:

```
expect_that(f2(x=1.4), throws_error("error \\[1\\]"))
```

seems to work.

Or you can specify `fixed=TRUE`:

```
expect_that(f2(x=1.4), throws_error("error [1]", fixed = TRUE))
```

Comment: or `expect_that(f2(x=1.4), throws_error("error [1]", fixed = TRUE))`